# Where do I pipe to file when using an inline <<EOF ... EOF?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am automating an ftp session, but I want to take stdout and pipe it to file. I have come up with 3 options:

**Option 1**

```
ftp -i ftpServer >stdoutFile <<EOF
cd somewhere
get something
EOF
```

**Option 2**

```
ftp -i ftpServer <<EOF >stdoutFile
cd somewhere
get something
EOF
```

**Option 3**

```
ftp -i ftpServer <<EOF
cd somewhere
get something
EOF > stdoutFile
```

I seem to be getting syntax errors with all of them, and none of them seem to work.

I feel like I've somehow got this to work before but I can't remember how.

**Edit**

The syntax errors are still present. It appears as though if I use this method with a here-document titled EOF, I can not use that delimeter anywhere else in the script - weird.

The exact error that is produced is actually a failure on the next if-statement termination. For example :

```
if [ condition ]
then
    ftp -i ftpServer >stdoutFile <<EOF
    cd somewhere
    get something
    EOF
fi

if [ something else ]
then
   somethingWithaHereDoc <<EOF
   foo
   bar
   EOF
fi
```

I get `Syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'` pointing to the line of the last fi.

<del>The FTP connection is hanging now. I'm using a ~/.bashrc file and it works in another console, but not in the script.</del> I accidentally had a named pipe in the directory, causing the ftp session to hang. All is resolved now. thanks!

The reason I am doing this is because I want to download a specific file from an ftp server. I am listing the directory content, exiting the ftp session and processing it in bash, and then starting another ftp session to get the file that I've chosen.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 should both work.

Comment: Please show the syntax errors you are getting, and the context.  Option 3 will certainly fail, but the first two should be OK.

Comment: Your first and second options above are correct, but your `EOF` must be the only thing on the line: no leading tabs or spaces, no trailing junk either. The problem you're seeing is bash is not recognising the terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<<EOF` only *signals* that a here document will begin *on the next line*. You can freely mix this with other redirections, so options 1 and 2 are both valid. There is no difference between the two, although I suspect most people would prefer and suggest option 1, as it does not appear to "interject" the output redirection into the here document.

If you are getting syntax errors with either option 1 or option 2, they are almost certainly unrelated to the here document itself.

Option 3 is invalid because the here document delimiter must occur on a line by itself, and because it is not part of the original command.

Comment: This helps my understanding, thanks. I've edited the question because I'm still having issues.

Comment: Please add an *exact* command that produces an error, along with the *exact* error. What you have now isn't enough to diagnose the problem. You should be able to use the delimiter elsewhere in the here document; only the delimiter by itself on a single line should terminate the here doc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to quote the first `EOF`. Option 3 wont terminate the heredoc, so it is wrong, but the other 2 should work (I generally use Option 2). Do you want `ssh` instead of `ftp` (ie, are you trying to preform an operation that produces output, or grabbing a file)? below is how I do ssh:

```
ssh ... << 'EOF' > file
remote commands here
EOF
```

can also pipe to a local process:

```
ssh ... << 'EOF' | awk ...
remote commands here
EOF
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest that quoting `EOF` is either necessary or incorrect; it depends solely on what the contents of the here document should be.

Comment: Your right, Quote is not always necissary, except that in this case, the contents of the heredoc explicitly include a cd, which probably isnt desired on the local server, but rather on the remote server. To execute it on the remote server, you have to quote it

Comment: @CSTobey, incorrect. The quotes prevent **expansions** from being run locally, but the `cd` isn't inside any kind of substitution or expansion. If it were, say, `$(cd somewhere; printf 'put %q\n' *.txt)`, not just `cd somewhere`, then you'd be right, but that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that the poster is giving psuedocode and listing intent, not what he is actually going to put in his heredoc. Perhaps it is a bad assumption, but his intent seems clear from the text.

Comment: Since `cd` is a valid FTP command, it looks like literal content to me.

Comment: His intent might be to run the FTP command `cd` with an argument provided by a `bash` variable (`cd $somedir`), in which case quoting would be decidedly incorrect.

Comment: ...I can't think of anything the OP might have intended whereby quoting the heredoc would be reasonably necessary to make the behavior of `cd` more correct. Keep in mind that if it *were* inside a substitution, ie. `$(cd somewhere)`, that would have no effect on the behavior of `ftp` or anything else, since the new directory changed to inside that subshell would be discarded the moment the subshell exited. You couldn't actually get a file from that other directory without fully qualifying its path, because the `ftp` command's local working directory would still be the one it was started in.